# Creating cursor connection again shows error

Tags: python, mysql, cursor, connection

I have a py program as shown below:

```
    sess_id = 1;
    print(sess_id)
    cursor_one = conn.cursor()
    cursor_one.execute("select time_arr from info where sess_id= '%s'" % 
    (sess_id))
    data=cursor_one.fetchone()
    print(type(data))
    print(data)
    print("datatwo conversions... start")
    cursor_two = conn.cursor()
    cursor_two.execute("select type from questions")
    data_two=cursor_two.fetchall()
```

this is my conn code :

```
    conn= mysql.connector.connect
    (user="root",password="",host="localhost",database="videojs")
```

Here the **cursor_one** suuccesfully compiles with no error but when i have used the same conn in **cursor_two** it shows error which should not have happened

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Ai_Edutech_trial_project 
\eclipse_workspace\Project\dbConn.py", line 117, in <module>
 read_from_db()
File 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\Ai_Edutech_trial_project 
\eclipse_workspace\Project\dbConn.py", line 23, in read_from_db
 cursor_two = conn.cursor()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 
  829, in cursor
  self.handle_unread_result()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 
 1093, in handle_unread_result
 raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
 mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found
```

and the erreor does not come in

```
 cursor_two.execute("select type from questions")
```

but in this line

```
 cursor_two = conn.cursor()
```

i have checked and probably its not the database error but something else .. please help me out

Comment: its not a duplicate it varies , can you please just suggest something

Comment: Somehow you forgot to explain why you think it is not a duplicate.

Comment: ok thanks well it resolved my issue